# list lambda or delegate find first result of expression

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda, foreach

Are these code return same result for find first result of expression?

```
        bool daily = false;
        lstDep.ForEach(d => daily = d.DailyAmount < transferedAmount ? true : false);
        lstDep.ForEach(delegate(DepositRoleModel d)
        {
            daily = d.DailyAmount < transferedAmount ? true : false;
        }
            );
```

How can I break foreach for first true result?

Comment: So you want us to do that for you?

Comment: I wanna compare and choose faster and reliable one.

Comment: @Ahmad: so **you** want it - then **you** take it and compare. Doesn't it sound logic for you?

Comment: @zerkms I edited my question, I don't want to continue foreach after first "true".

Comment: @Ahmad: you don't need to break it, but you need to use [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) instead. Now you see - that it **always** makes sense to explain the *original* task, not to show just a (wrong/broken) solution expecting us to guess whet you *really* want to solve.

Comment: @zerkms sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use instead this query:

```
bool daily = lstDep.Any(d=>d.DailyAmount < transferedAmount)
```

It will work faster than your queries.
This code is equivalent to:

```
bool daily;

foreach(var d in lstDep)
{
    daily = d.DailyAmount < transferedAmount;
    if(daily)
        break;
}
```

Comment: "It will work faster than your queries." --- how can you compare the solutions that do **different** job and provide different results? :-)

Comment: Do you want to say that this query will execute slower than his? :) And of cause that solution do different job, but this job exactly what he wants to do.

Comment: No, I want to say that it's **impossible** to compare apples and oranges. Indeed it does what OP wants but it's incomparable to the code from the original question, because that code does different job.

Comment: :) I see what you want with this question but I think goolge search and VS code analyzing can help!!! Thank you @zerkms :)

Comment: @Ahmad: And what I "want"? I wanted to teach you how to ask proper questions and explain about incomparable things. But seems like I failed my aim.

Comment: @zerkms No no no, I learned somethings good. Thank you very much. Again, sorry for my faults.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to "break the Foreach" but use [`.Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) instead:

```
bool daily = lstDep.Any(d => d.DailyAmount < transferedAmount);
```